# Module to wrap generic Timer

Tags: tinyos, nesc

I am trying to write a module to wrap a generic Timer, but I would like to use this module to be able to wrap timers with arbitrary precision, without writing duplicated code.

I wrote the module like that, but it complains that precision_tag is missing a type, but also giving it a type it won't compile.

```
generic module TimerLoggerP(precision_tag) {
    provides {
        interface Timer<precision_tag> as Timer;
        interface LoggerComponent;
    }

    uses {
        interface Timer<precision_tag> as RTimer;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to make it work in the generic way I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needs the special *typedef* type.

```
generic module TimerLoggerP(typedef precision_tag) {
    provides {
        interface Timer<precision_tag> as Timer;
        interface LoggerComponent;
    }

    uses {
        interface Timer<precision_tag> as RTimer;
    }
}
```